# How to import data into a table from another similar table?

Tags: postgresql, spatial-database

I am working with PostgreSQL to import a table from a .shp file and my task is to populate another table (same attributes as this .shp table) with the data of the table of the .shp file table that i just created.

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE!  As a new user be sure to take the [Tour].  I think you should **edit** your question to provide more precise details of what you are wanting to to do, what you have tried and where you are stuck.

Answer (score 1):

There are several tools you can use to achieve a format conversion like this, among them, in no particular order:

- Open Source Server solution: GeoServer, which has capabilities to import various files and store them in a PostGIS db. Info is available here: http://docs.geoserver.org/2.6.x/en/user/data/vector/shapefile.html
- Open Source Desktop Solution: wetransform HALE supports reading from Shapefile and writing to PostGIS databases. Info is available here: https://www.wetransform.to/products/hale
- Proprietary Desktop + Server Solution: Safe Software FME, which can convert hundreds of formats into each other.

Disclosure: I have been on the HALE team in the past.